# in Room, Why I could @insert a row in a table but unable to retrieve it with SQL request?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-room

I have a problem with room (my fist time with room).

I can insert some data in my DB but not retrieve something. I'm stuck with this problem. If you can explain me.

I explain :
I use Android Architecture Components. So I have an DAO to make my SQL requests. I have a repository to not handle my DB directly.

And finally, I have a viewModel to be not worry by the data persistance.
My DAO uses the annotation @Insert to create a row .
I use Stetho to look through my DB and everything is oK.

My row is created.
So, When I want to get it with another SQL request (by the same way DAO => repository =>ViewModel), 
my request returns always null.

```
// --- DAO --- 

@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id")
LiveData<RealEstate> getRealEstate(long id);


// --- REPOSITORY --- 

 private final RealEstateDao realEstateDao;

public RealEstateRepository(RealEstateDao realEstateDao) { this.realEstateDao = realEstateDao; }

public LiveData<RealEstate> getRealEstate(long id) { return this.realEstateDao.getRealEstate(id); }

// --- VIEWMODEL --- 

public LiveData<RealEstate> getUser(long userId) {
    return userDataSource.getRealEstate(userId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using incorrectly LiveData, Room have bridge adapter for RXJava/Kotlin, Coroutines, etc.

First, change the return value to something like this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id")
RealEstate getRealEstate(long id);
```

Remember that you cannot make database operations in the Main Thread, you should be using a mechanism for that RX, Coroutines, threads, etc.

After this, you can use LiveData in your viewmodel wrapping the data retrieved from your database to notify their UI parent.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your comment, I find the solution. You were right. I used LiveData Incorrectly.

Comment: We can indeed use `LiveData` in the `DAO` directly check out this  https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47